# Jenkins Restored Job is not visible

Tags: jenkins

We have restored a job on Jenkins server from our last backup. But its not visible on UI.

I have tried reloading configuration from disk and even restarted the service , still not visible.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: does your issue got resolved, based on that other users can answer or try the same.

Answer (score 1):

Did you restore only the config.xml file (and its parent folder)?

Did you check the permissions on the restored file (or folder)?

Did you check the "All" view in Jenkins?

If you are using a direct path to your job (like http://your.jenkins.ci/jobs/myjob), does it work?